# SEO directories - good or bad?

Tags: seo, html5, language, directory

I am building my first blog that will provide quality information about a specific niche ( make up, fashion etc. haven't decided yet ). I am intending for it to be as high on the google page as possible, but am a SEO noob. Obviously, I know quality content is the most important part of SEO, but it must be helped by proper SEO so I am trying to get some help in starting up -

- Does it make much of a difference if I code my site in HTML5 in terms of SEO [ use of < article >, < header > tags ]  ?
- Can I do my site in 2 languages ? Does it hurt SEO ?
- I have heard SEO directories are the way to go in terms of improving SEO but how should I approach this ? Should I use a tool for submitting to dirs or should I do it manually ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it make much of a difference if I code my site in HTML5 in terms of SEO [ use of < article >, < header > tags ] ?

[As of right now it makes no difference for SEO.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/what-are-the-seo-rules-for-html-5) Obviously that will change in the future.

> Can I do my site in 2 languages ? Does it hurt SEO ?

No. [Here is what Google recommends for multi lingual sites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html).

> I have heard SEO directories are the way to go in terms of improving SEO but how should I approach this ? Should I use a tool for submitting to dirs or should I do it manually ?

These directories will have little value. You'll need to do a lot of submitting for this to have any real effect on your rankings. But for many new sites it's all they really have at first. Doing this is a good idea but I don't recommend doing reciprocal links with these directories. The chance of you being snared in a link farm is very real and that can get you into big trouble. Make sure all of your links are one way links only.

I find that the tools that do automated submissions to crappy jobs. Stay away from them and do it manually. There are browser extensions that make this easy to do. This will also allow you to verify the sites you are submitting to are quality sites and you are placed in the appropriate category.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you recommend any firefox extensions for this ?

Comment: @digitalzoomstudio, Informenter and clippings are good for this. They make filling out the forms easier. If you are a javascript programmer a greasemonkey script can be real handy.